# Clock synchronazation in special relativity using signal other than light

Tags: special-relativity

I'm reading Taylor & Wheeler "Spacetime Physics" and have a question about possibility of correct clock synch using signal other then light.

For example, we choose reference clock(A) and at time=0 throw a ball, not light wave, to other clock(B) we wish to synchronize. A ball has constant velocity in our inertial frame and we know distance between clocks. So, as in the case of light wave, we can preset clock B to the time required for ball to fly between clocks, and start clock B after ball hits;

Is it, in pure theory, a correct method of synch? If not, why?

Comment: How can you measure or know the velocity of the ball without having a synchronization procedure? In the case of the light we assume by hypothesis that the velocity is constant and this fact turns out to be consistent, and also true in closed paths.

Comment: I understand that using light as synchronization signal in much more convenient, because light has known constant velocity by definition.

Comment: We can measure velocity of the ball using other pair of clocks and assuming that they have been synchronized by "standard" method. The question is if we know velocity (ignoring measurement method), can we use such non-light signal to sych clocks? As far as I understand, yes.

Comment: Yes you can. In particular, if you know the velocity because you have measured it exploiting Einstein's synchronization, the new synchronization procedure performed by throwing the ball will turn out to in agreement with Einstein's one.